# Hierarchical JSON output from table

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I've got this table structure

```
| User | Type    | Data |
|------|---------|------|
| 1    | "T1"    | "A"  |
| 1    | "T1"    | "B"  |
| 1    | "T2"    | "C"  |
| 2    | "T1"    | "D"  |
```

I want to get a hierarchical JSON string returned from my query

```
{
  "1": {
    "T1": [
      "A",
      "B"
    ],
    "T2": [
      "C"
    ]
  },
  "2": {
    "T1": [
      "D"
    ]
  }
}
```

So one entry for each `User` with a sub-entry for each `Type` and then a sub-entry for each `Data`

All I'm finding is the `FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('x')` or `AUTO` statement but nothing that would make this hierarchical. Is this even possible out of the box? I couldn't find anything so I've experimented with (recursive) CTE but didn't get very far. I'd much appreciate if someone could just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can create `JSON` with variable key names using `FOR JSON AUTO` and `FOR JSON PATH`. I suggest the following solutions:

- using `FOR XML PATH` to generate `JSON` with string manipulations
- using `STRING_AGG()` to generate `JSON` with string manipulations for SQL Server 2017+
- using `STRING_AGG()` and `JSON_MODIFY()` for SQL Server 2017+

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #InputData (
   [User] int,
   [Type] varchar(2),
   [Data] varchar(1)
)
INSERT INTO #InputData 
   ([User], [Type], [Data])
VALUES
   (1, 'T1', 'A'),
   (1, 'T1', 'B'),
   (1, 'T2', 'C'),
   (2, 'T1', 'D')
```

Statement using `FOR XML PATH`:

```
;WITH SecondLevelCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      d.[User],
      d.[Type],
      Json1 = CONCAT(
         '[', 
         STUFF(
         (
         SELECT CONCAT(',"', [Data], '"')
         FROM #InputData 
         WHERE [User] = d.[User] AND [Type] = d.[Type]
         FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, ''),
         ']')
   FROM #InputData d
   GROUP BY d.[User], d.[Type]
), FirstLevelCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      d.[User],
      Json2 = CONCAT(
         '{',
         STUFF(
         (
         SELECT CONCAT(',"', [Type], '":', [Json1])
         FROM SecondLevelCTE 
         WHERE [User] = d.[User]
         FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, ''),
         '}'
      )
   FROM SecondLevelCTE d
   GROUP BY d.[User]
)
SELECT CONCAT(
   '{',
   STUFF(
   (
   SELECT CONCAT(',"', [User], '":', Json2)
   FROM FirstLevelCTE
   FOR XML PATH('')
   ), 1, 1, '')   ,
   '}'
)
```

Statement using `STRING_AGG()`:

```
;WITH SecondLevelCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      d.[User],
      d.[Type],
      Json1 = (
         SELECT CONCAT('["', STRING_AGG([Data], '","'), '"]')
         FROM #InputData 
         WHERE [User] = d.[User] AND [Type] = d.[Type]
      )
   FROM #InputData d
   GROUP BY d.[User], d.[Type]
), FirstLevelCTE AS (
   SELECT 
      d.[User],
      Json2 = (
         SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', [Type], '":', [Json1]), ',')
         FROM SecondLevelCTE
         WHERE [User] = d.[User]
      )
   FROM SecondLevelCTE d
   GROUP BY d.[User]
)
SELECT CONCAT('{', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', [User], '":{', Json2, '}'), ','), '}')
FROM FirstLevelCTE
```

Statement using `STRING_AGG()` and `JSON_MODIFY()`:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{}'
SELECT 
   @json = JSON_MODIFY(
      CASE 
         WHEN JSON_QUERY(@json, CONCAT('$."', [User] , '"')) IS NULL THEN JSON_MODIFY(@json, CONCAT('$."', [User] , '"'), JSON_QUERY('{}'))
         ELSE @json
      END,
      CONCAT('$."', [User] , '".', [Type]), 
      JSON_QUERY(Json)
   )
FROM (
   SELECT 
      d.[User],
      d.[Type],
      Json = (
         SELECT CONCAT('["', STRING_AGG([Data], '","'), '"]')
         FROM #InputData 
         WHERE [User] = d.[User] AND [Type] = d.[Type]
      )
   FROM #InputData d
   GROUP BY d.[User], d.[Type]
) t
```

Output:

```
{"1":{"T1":["A","B"],"T2":["C"]},"2":{"T1":["D"]}}
```

Comment: Great stuff. I'm limited to SQL2016 so the top one works for me. I've done more reading on it and there appears to be no other way. It seems like it's not a too well performing way of doing it, though, with the string manipulations etc...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you want (I'm not great with FOR JSON) but it does get you close to the shape you need until something better comes along... 
(https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser/974b6b)

```
use tempdb
GO

drop table if exists users
create table users (
    [user] integer
    , [type] char(2)
    , [data] char(1)
)


insert into users 
values (1, 'T1', 'A')
    , (1, 'T1', 'B')
    , (1, 'T2', 'C')
    , (2, 'T1', 'D')

select DISTINCT ONE.[user], two.[type], three.[data] 
from users AS ONE
inner join users two
    on one.[user] = two.[user]
inner join users three
    on one.[user] = three.[user]
    and two.[type] = three.[type]
for JSON AUTO
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it seems like there is no way around string manipulation to achieve this. A shame as I need it to perform really well.